# Eclipse - How to import all C++ project setting?

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide, settings

I want to copy all project settings from an existing C++ project to an other one. I know there is an import-export for C++ project settings but that only uses "Include Paths" and "Headers". There are a lot more options like compiler / linker options build / run configurations. Any way to import / export those?

[image: Eclipse C++]

Comment: Another annoying thing about eclipse is that imported properties are copied, not linked. So there is no way to keep a common project properties file to modify properties of several projects at once like in Visual Studio.

Comment: @VTT I can kinda live with that, as long as I can "copy" those settings but this import-export only imports a few of the many settings.